# Matplotlib drawing different lines for plots with same data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to visualize 2 different variables in the same plot.
When I draw them apart from each other everything works fine.
But when I draw them together in one plot, matplotlib starts drawing random lines between datapoints.
I use the following code to draw my graphs and save them to a pdf file:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

mobility_2020 = pd.read_csv("Datasets\\2020_BE_Region_Mobility_Report.csv")
mobility_2021 = pd.read_csv("Datasets\\2021_BE_Region_Mobility_Report.csv")
cases = pd.read_csv("Datasets\COVID19BE_CASES_AGESEX.csv")
cases = cases.dropna(subset=["DATE"])

mobility = pd.concat([mobility_2020, mobility_2021])

mobility['sub_region_2'].mask(mobility['sub_region_2'] == 'Antwerp', 'Antwerpen', inplace=True)
mobility['sub_region_2'].mask(mobility['sub_region_2'] == 'East Flanders', 'OostVlaanderen', inplace=True)
mobility['sub_region_2'].mask(mobility['sub_region_2'] == 'Flemish Brabant', 'VlaamsBrabant', inplace=True)
mobility['sub_region_2'].mask(mobility['sub_region_2'] == 'Province of Namur', 'Namur', inplace=True)
mobility['sub_region_2'].mask(mobility['sub_region_2'] == 'Walloon Brabant', 'BrabantWallon', inplace=True)
mobility['sub_region_2'].mask(mobility['sub_region_2'] == 'West Flanders', 'WestVlaanderen', inplace=True)
mobility['sub_region_2'].mask(mobility['sub_region_2'] == 'Liege', 'Liège', inplace=True)

provinces = ["VlaamsBrabant", "WestVlaanderen", "OostVlaanderen", "Namur", "Luxembourg", "Limburg", "Liège", "Hainaut", "Brussels", "BrabantWallon", "Antwerpen"]
sectors = ["retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline", "grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline", "parks_percent_change_from_baseline", "transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline", "workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline", "residential_percent_change_from_baseline"]

with PdfPages('report.pdf') as pdf:
    for province in provinces:
        for sector in sectors:
            data_province = (cases[cases["PROVINCE"] == province])
            data_province = data_province.groupby("DATE", as_index=False).sum()[0:100]
            data_province = data_province.sort_values("DATE")
            if province == "Brussels":
                data_sector = (mobility[mobility["sub_region_1"] == province])[0:100]
            else:
                data_sector = (mobility[mobility["sub_region_2"] == province])[0:100]
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.plot(data_province["DATE"], data_province["CASES"], label=f"New cases {province}")
            ax.plot(data_sector["date"], data_sector[sector], label=f"Mobility {sector}")
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=100))
            plt.xlabel("Dates")
            ax.yaxis.grid()
            plt.title(f"Mobility {sector} for {province}")
            plt.legend()
            pdf.savefig()
            plt.close()
```

This is a result for when I just draw the data from the data_sector dataframe.
[image]

This is a result when I draw both of the dataframes.
[image]

I have no idea why this bug appears.
Might it just be a visual bug?

A small snippet from the files used:

2020_BE_Region_Mobility_Report.csv and 2021_BE_Region_Mobility_Report.csv

```
country_region_code,country_region,sub_region_1,sub_region_2,metro_area,iso_3166_2_code,census_fips_code,place_id,date,retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline,grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline,parks_percent_change_from_baseline,transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline,workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline,residential_percent_change_from_baseline
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-01,-82,-83,9,-71,-83,28
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-02,-53,-15,7,-40,-23,14
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-03,-58,-17,-1,-43,-14,10
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-04,-36,0,-26,-40,-30,14
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-05,-37,0,-11,-39,-30,14
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-06,-36,-3,-14,-39,-28,13
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-07,-44,-7,-26,-41,-29,15
BE,Belgium,,,,,,ChIJl5fz7WR9wUcR8g_mObTy60c,2021-01-08,-46,-4,-22,-39,-27,16
```

COVID19BE_CASES_AGESEX.csv

```
"DATE","PROVINCE","REGION","AGEGROUP","SEX","CASES"
"2020-03-01","Antwerpen","Flanders","40-49","M",1
"2020-03-01","Brussels","Brussels","10-19","F",1
"2020-03-01","Brussels","Brussels","10-19","M",1
"2020-03-01","Brussels","Brussels","20-29","M",1
"2020-03-01","Brussels","Brussels","30-39","F",1
"2020-03-01","Brussels","Brussels","40-49","F",1
"2020-03-01","Brussels","Brussels","50-59","M",1
"2020-03-01","Liège","Wallonia","40-49","M",3
"2020-03-01","Limburg","Flanders","70-79","M",1
"2020-03-01","OostVlaanderen","Flanders","50-59","F",1
"2020-03-01","VlaamsBrabant","Flanders","10-19","F",2
"2020-03-01","VlaamsBrabant","Flanders","10-19","M",1
"2020-03-01","VlaamsBrabant","Flanders","40-49","F",1
"2020-03-01","VlaamsBrabant","Flanders","40-49","M",1
"2020-03-01","VlaamsBrabant","Flanders","50-59","M",1
"2020-03-01","VlaamsBrabant","Flanders","60-69","M",1
"2020-03-02","Antwerpen","Flanders","40-49","M",1
"2020-03-02","BrabantWallon","Wallonia","10-19","F",1
"2020-03-02","BrabantWallon","Wallonia","10-19","M",1
"2020-03-02","Brussels","Brussels","10-19","F",1
"2020-03-02","Brussels","Brussels","40-49","M",1
```

This is the plot of the same data without constraints of the length.

[image]

Comment: This typically happens when your data is not sorted by date. Try `data_sector.sort_values("date")[sector]` if data_sector is a pandas.Dataframe.

Comment: This can happen when your x values are not sorted. Maybe `data_sector.sort_values("DATE")` similar to how you do it with `data_province` already helps?

Comment: Sorting the data doesn't help. I can see that there is a gap of missing dates for the X-axis. I don't know if that could be the reason for the strange result but that's the only thing odd thing I see

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At very least show how the objects your refer to in your question were created e.g. `provinces`, `sectors`, `cases` and include your imports. At some point you might be plotting `int`s (or similar) instead `datetime` objects.

Comment: I included my entire script and some snippets of the used csv's

Comment: I think you're problem lies with your x values for `mobility` line. Check `data_sector["date"]` to make sure that the dates have been parse correctly, I'd recommend explicitly using the `dayfirst` argument of `pd.read_csv` because the dates in your snippets could be either dayfirst or monthfirst (pandas default). And check that your sorted values are also correct/what you'd expect.

Comment: Even using the dayFirst argument doesn't seem to do the job. The values are ordered in the way I expect. It's odd to see that the data on it's own plots fine but the 2 combined break something.

Comment: The figures in your question aren't the same length of time. The top figure with just a blue line stops earlier (it stops just at the point where your problem starts on the lower figure) than the bottom figure with blue and orange lines.  You could have some data which is missing or malformed. If you plot from the 2020-05-10 onwards I think you'll see the same problem regardless of whether you have other lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233441/discussion-between-jason-and-mkay).